# Assertion failed: (result == KERN_SUCCESS), function +[XPCMachSendRight wrapSendRight:]

Tags: ios

In my IOS app, I'm sometimes getting the above error after a 3rd party library call, which seems to be allocating some memory, albeit not much (about 13MB);
Assertion failed: (result == KERN_SUCCESS), function +[XPCMachSendRight wrapSendRight:], file /SourceCache/XPCObjects/XPCObjects-46/XPCMachSendRight.m, line 27.

there's no indication where or why this is happening, and I couldn't find any help or even similar problems on the internet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It happens when we call function before completion of another, i.e. it's threading problem. So check for that. For example: 
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        // correct place for code after completion
    }];

// wrong place for code after completion

Comment: That fixed it for me.  In my case I was using the MFMailComposeViewController and needed to move some other clean-up code into the completion section.  The other code seemed unrelated... but it wasn't.